# How can I permanently sync a folder with azcopy to Azure Blobstore?

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I wrote a Powershell script using azcopy to sync a local folder to my azure blob store account.
When the script is finished it states that all the files have been successfully uploaded.

I want to re-start the script permanently as soon as it finished. So the folder is permanently synced with the cloud. Is this possible? how?

Comment: Use windows scheduler to run it every five minutes?

Comment: Yes, you could. As Nick said, it's better to [create a basic task using Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize local storage with Azure Blob storage by using the [AzCopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) command-line utility, i.e., you can [synchronize the contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-synchronize?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) of your local file system with a blob container.

Note that this synchronization is *one way*. In other words, you choose which of these two endpoints is the **source** and which one is the **destination**.

In your case, the container is the destination, and the local file system is the source.

Here is the Syntax:

```
azcopy sync 'https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>' 'C:\myDirectory' --recursive
```

and an example:

```
azcopy sync 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' 'C:\myDirectory' --recursive
```

Command reference: [azcopy sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync)

**Note:** If you set the `--delete-destination` flag to `true` (default `false`), AzCopy deletes files without providing a prompt. If you want a prompt to appear before AzCopy deletes a file, set the `--delete-destination` flag to `prompt`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But as I wrote I already syncing my files with azcopy. The question is how can I permanently sync a folder? like dropbox.

Comment: @Julian Oh, sry I minsunderstood. I don't think azcopy sync is meant for that purpose. That said, creating an Azure File Share and [mounting it on your machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#mount-the-azure-file-share) has a similar effect. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Julian Have you had a chance to check?

Comment: Hi @Bhargavi Annadevara: Iam syncing huge amount of files with Azcopy currently. Bascially we are using Azure Blobstore as huge data backup. We are syncing JPGs. Like 500.000 images per day. Would Azure File Share a good option for that? Or will there be problems, as we are syncing so much files? Some folders on Azure have currently 8-10 Million files.